# MySQL query error when using NOT EXISTS()

Tags: sql, mysql, legacy-database

I am trying to run a MySQL query utilising the `NOT EXISTS` MySQL function on a legacy system (running MySQL 4.x), below is a simple query that return a few columns from two tables (with one INNER JOIN).

NB `customerId` and `accountId` are the same values.. it is a really old system :(

```
SELECT d.customerId, d.customerName, a.status
    FROM DetailedDebtorsData AS d 
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.account_uid = d.customerId
    ORDER BY d.date ASC;
```

```
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
| customerId    | customerName         | status |
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
|        145060 | Alan Smith           | active |
|         68742 | John Doe             | active |
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
```

I have another table that I will be using as an 'exceptions' table, in essence if the customerId (with its related account_id column in the exclusions) is found in the `account_payment_terms` exceptions table then I DON'T want return the related row from the DetailedDebtors table above.

`account_payment_terms` table (for exclusions)

```
mysql> SELECT account_id, created_date FROM account_payment_terms;
+------------+---------------------+
| account_id | created_date        |
+------------+---------------------+
|     145060 | 2023-11-20 13:23:03 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

As the account_id `145060` exists in the `accountPaymentTerms` table, then I do not want to return the associated row (that has the same 145060 id) in the `DetailedDebtors` table to be returned.

**Here is the query I am trying to execute with NOT EXISTS()**

```
SELECT d.customerId, d.customerName, a.status
    FROM DetailedDebtorsData AS d 
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.account_uid = d.customerId
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM account_payment_terms AS apt
        WHERE apt.account_id = d.customerId
    )        
    ORDER BY d.date ASC;
```

This errors and gives me the following error, but I want the WHERE NOT EXISTS to simply only return the one row , the row that IS NOT in the `account_payment_terms` table.

Error returned in MySQL

```
ERROR 1064 (HY000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM account_payment_terms AS
```

Expected Outcome (return 1 row)

```
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
| accountId     | customerName         | status |
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
|         68742 | John Doe             | active |
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Actual Outcome (returns 2 row)

```
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
| accountId     | customerName         | status |
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
|        145060 | Alan Smith           | active |
|         68742 | John Doe             | active |
+---------------+----------------------+--------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exact version is it? Run `SELECT VERSION();`. IIRC, MySQL older than 4.1 does not support subqueries, so `EXISTS(<subquery>)` will not work. When we needed to do exclusion joins, there was an outer join solution, which I will post if you need it.

Comment: Oh wow... I am running 4.0.24 :(

Comment: Wow indeed - are you stuck with that version?

Comment: thanks @BillKarwin omg.. old legacy systems are the worst - thanks for that I figured it out

Comment: @P.Salmon I am unfortunately for the time being... I know it is 2023 how is MySQL 4.0 still a thing on planet Earth.. I also don't understand this :(

Comment: For the record, 4.0.24 was released 2005-03-04 according to the release notes! That database instance is old enough to vote in the US! LOL

Comment: That is a hilarious comment! @BillKarwin I hope you don't mind me stealing that quote :-)

Comment: Be my guest. And seriously, that version of MySQL is undoubtedly full of security vulnerabilities, and I would assume all the other components of this legacy system are too. It needs to be upgraded or decommissioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution to do an exclusion join à la MySQL 4.0:

```
SELECT d.customerId, d.customerName, a.status
FROM DetailedDebtorsData AS d 
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.account_uid = d.customerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN account_payment_terms AS apt
  ON apt.account_id = d.customerId
WHERE apt.account_id IS NULL
ORDER BY d.date ASC;
```

Comment: awesome bill! I have never used such an old version of MySQL and cannot believe NOT EXISTS wasn't a thing.. I need sleep thanks again